# Export CSV with multiple field-value expressions?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm trying to get all the field-value pairs into the same CSV.

### Works Individually

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine -Recurse

($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Key Usage"}).Format(0) |
  Select-Object -Property @{Name="Key Usage";Expression={$_}} |
  Export-csv -Path .\KeyUsage.csv

($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Basic Constraints"}).Format(0) |
  Select-Object -Property @{Name="basic constraints";Expression={$_}} |
  Export-csv -Path .\BasicConstraints.csv
```

### Does not work

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine -Recurse

($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Key Usage"}).Format(0) |
  Select-Object -Property @{Name="Key Usage";Expression={$_}},
($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Basic Constraints"}).Format(0) |
  Select-Object - Property @{Name="basic constraints";Expression={$_}} |
Export-csv -Path .\File.csv
```

Perhaps I need to check to see if the field-value is null, but how do I check that within the 'Expression'? It doesn't look like I can use `if(!$_){}else{}` to write in some zero'd values.

Comment: Wouldn't the output be useless? You don't have any identifiers that you can map to individual certificates, just a list of "Key Usage" values

Comment: I don't think `Select-Object -Property @{Name="Key Usage";Expression={$_}}, ($cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Basic Constraints"}).Format(0)` is a valid expression.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Thanks for the resposne, yes it would be useless because there is no identifiers. I do have some more scripting to help with identifying each certificate but I left all of that out as I just need to test this particular piece of the puzzle

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers I'll take another look but it returns values on my certificate store... [edit]Just tried it out and I get values so it should be good. Both the expressions work just fine by themselves but upon combining them it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Listing the items without having an identifier to associate them with is pointless. I can appreciate wanting to keep questions specific to the issue at hand, but it still needs to fit into the bigger picture, and with what you have given us that isn't realistic. What you are presenting is a pretty common issue for people trying to output to CSV objects with nested arrays. Excluding the identifiers for those arrays only complicates things in the long run.

Comment: I agree with the points made in previous comments.  Knowing what you are trying to achieve is important to the people who want to help you.  More than once, the best answer has turned out to be a different approach to the fundamental problem, rather than what you view as a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician My apologies for not including additional information. I hope I can improve on my questions I might have in the future, I'll make sure to read the posting guidance to better myself on that front.

Comment: @walter-mitty You like the others have a valid point, in general I am using the Thumbprint of each certificate for identification. I will do a better job of making clarifications for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post the final resolution for others. Via the Microsoft PowerShell community I got a response that helped me resolve the problem -

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine -Recurse |
Select-Object
@{N="Key_Usage";E={($_.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Key Usage"}).Format(0)}},
@{N="Basic_Constraints";E={($_.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Basic Constraints"}).Format(0)}} |
Export-Csv .\File.csv -notype
```